# How to check whether FTP login is successful or not in Python ftplib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, ftplib

I am developing a FTP client using Python ftplib. Here is my code:

```
def connectftp():
ftp=ftplib.FTP('hostname')
print(ftp.getwelcome())
ftp.login(username, password)
```

I want to display a message saying `"Login successful"` when the FTP login is successful. How to do that? How to check whether the login is successful or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`FTP.login` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.login) throws an exception, when an authentication fails, so you can simply do:

```
ftp.login(username, password)
print("Login successful")
```

If you want to react to authentication failures as well, handle the exception:

```
try:
    ftp.login(username, password)
    print("Login successful")
    # do your FTP stuff here
except:
    print("Login failed")
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is

```py
def connectftp():
    ftp=ftplib.FTP('hostname')
    print(ftp.getwelcome())
    ftp.login(username, password)
    login_response = ftp.login(username, password)
    print(login_response)
```

login_response should be '230 Login successful.'

You can check the ftplib documentation here
https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html